# Clip-Path vs Border-Radius issue when window is resized

Tags: svg, responsive, clip-path

I want to use an SVG as a `clip-path` to round the edges of an image. Yes, I must do it in this way for various reasons .

PROBLEM:
When the browser window is resized, the points and handles that form the rounded corners adjust to the changing size of the image (bounding box) because I'm using `clipPathUnits="ObjectBoundingBox"`. This causes the rounded edges to loose their "roundness" and look overall really bad. The CSS `border-radius` property doesn't have this issue. No matter how you resize the browser window, the edges of a div clipped with `border-radius` never loose their round shape. The problem is most apparent when you resize the browser window to it's most narrow or widest possible state. Try that with this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Wcomp/pen/dwZbEd?editors=1100) and you'll see what I mean. The top image uses `border-radius` and the bottom image uses `clip-path`. Is there any way to force the ONLY rounded edges of the SVG clip-path to stay equally rounded no matter how the image is resized without sacrificing the responsiveness of the clip-path dimensions? Is this even possible? I'm totally open to a JavaScript solution if there is one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can trick the `<svg>` element to have just the same dimensions as the image and then size the clip-path with relative units. The downside is that you cannot reuse these paths but have to define one for every individual image.

```css
.box {
  left: 5%;
  height: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#box1 {
  top: 5%;
  width: 50%;
  clip-path: url(#clipPath1);
}
#box2 {
  top: 55%;
  width: 90%;
  clip-path: url(#clipPath2);
}

.flower{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box1">
    <img class="flower" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="none">
    <svg>
        <clipPath id="clipPath1" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" rx="20" ry="20"/>
      </clipPath>
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="box" id="box2">
    <img class="flower" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="none">
    <svg>
        <clipPath id="clipPath2" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" rx="20" ry="20"/>
      </clipPath>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful! Seems like its working. Never thought of that. Thanks!